# LeetCode 375: Guess Number Higher or Lower II

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge, c++17, dynamic-programming

I'm posting my C++ code for LeetCode's Guess Number Higher or Lower II. If you have time and would like to review, please do so.

### Problem

> We are playing the Guess Game. The game is as follows:
>
> - I pick a number from 1 to n. You have to guess which number I picked.
> - Every time you guess wrong, I'll tell you whether the number I picked is higher or lower.
> - However, when you guess a particular number x, and you guess wrong, you pay $x. You win the game when you guess the number I picked.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> First round:  You guess 5, I tell you that it's higher. You pay $5.
> Second round: You guess 7, I tell you that it's higher. You pay $7.
> Third round:  You guess 9, I tell you that it's lower. You pay $9.
>
> Game over. 8 is the number I picked.
> ```
>
> - You end up paying $5 + $7 + $9 = $21.
> - Given a particular n ≥ 1, find out how much money you need to have to guarantee a win.

#### Accepted C++

```
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
    std::size_t getMoneyAmount(const std::size_t num) {
        std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t>> dp(num + 1, std::vector<std::size_t>(num + 1, 0));
        return get_dp(1, num, dp);
    }

private:
    std::size_t get_dp(const std::size_t head, const std::size_t tail, std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t>>& dp) {
        if (head >= tail) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (dp[head][tail] != 0) {
            return dp[head][tail];
        }

        std::size_t guesses = INT_MAX;

        for (std::size_t guess = head; guess < tail; guess++) {
            std::size_t max_guess = guess + max(get_dp(head, guess - 1, dp), get_dp(guess + 1, tail, dp));
            guesses = min(guesses, max_guess);
        }

        dp[head][tail] = guesses;
        return dp[head][tail];
    }
};
```

#### LeetCode's Java Solution (Not for review)

```
public class Solution {
    public int getMoneyAmount(int n) {
        int[][] dp = new int[n + 1][n + 1];

        for (int len = 2; len <= n; len++) {
            for (int start = 1; start <= n - len + 1; start++) {
                int minres = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for (int piv = start + (len - 1) / 2; piv < start + len - 1; piv++) {
                    int res = piv + Math.max(dp[start][piv - 1], dp[piv + 1][start + len - 1]);
                    minres = Math.min(res, minres);
                }
                dp[start][start + len - 1] = minres;
            }

        }
        return dp[1][n];
    }
}
```

#### Reference

On LeetCode, there is a class usually named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/guess-number-higher-or-lower-ii/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/guess-number-higher-or-lower-ii/discuss/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is difficult to read, there are no comments to explain what the code is doing, or how it’s doing it.

Using typedefs would also add explanations to the purpose of the code.

More verbose variable names would also help, dp doesn’t mean anything.

To me it looks like you have ported the code without understanding what it is doing, which has its place, but if you don’t understand it then how is anyone else meant to?